# Exception between threads. How many std::exception_ptr and synchronization I need?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, exception

I am a bit confused, but my question is simple.

I have a bunch of threads, I want to centralize error handling by treating all exceptions in the main thread after sent by other threads.

1. Do I use a shared `exception_ptr` global and use `std::current_exception()` in every `catch` clause in every thread? Or do I need to have different `excpetion_ptr` objects for different threads? I would like to keep all exceptions.
2. once the `current_exception` is assigned to an `exc_ptr` variable, when I access the `exc_ptr` from the main thread, do I need to synchronize the read from the main thread?

Comment: Yes, of course you need "t". You can't type the word "thread" without it.

Comment: Yes you need the right synchronization, though I like std::async/std:: future for that

Comment: You have various exceptions in various threads and you want to handle all of them in another thread? How is that useful/maintainable/feasible?

Comment: Normally you throw exceptions by value and catch by reference. No pointers, shared or otherwise, are needed, and also no synchronisation and no `std::current_exception` (it is for *truly* exceptional cases).

Comment: "I want to centralize error handling". It is unclear what exactly you mean by that.

Comment: @n.m. edited. Anyway this is not the main point of the question, I think.

Comment: @n.m. I do need std::current_exception in this case, I am sure: I need to transport exceptions from one thread to another one.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. Do you need to transport the exception at the time of thread::join?

Comment: No, at any time. I mean, there are two threads with a while loop. and those could generate some exception. The main thread will check for exception_ptr all the time if something was generated, then rethrow in main thread.

Comment: "will check for exception_ptr all the time" in a busy-wait loop? why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to propagate to the main thread only those exceptions that are not handled by the subordinate thread. This means you only need to use `exception_ptr` at the very top level handler of the subordinate thread.

I think the easiest approach is to have a global *container* (e.g. a producer/consumer queue) of `exception_ptr`s. Each top-level thread exception handler pushes its exception to the queue and exits. The main handler pulls exceptions from the queue and rethrows. Of course you need a proper synchronisation for the queue. Once you pull an `exceoption_ptr` off the queue you don't need to synchronize it, because the thread that has created it won't touch it any more.

It should also be possible to have a single global `exception_ptr` (equivalent to a queue of capacity 1, and synchronised in much the same way).